# Can ping to all computers and internet but router fails

Tags: networking, router, ping

I have an interesting issue.

Server is Windows Server 2012R2, only change done to it recently was an upgrade to SSD.

The server can see all the computers on the local LAN, and can see the internet. However, when I ping the router I get a general failure. This doesn't occur on any of the other computers and they can ping both the router and the server.

So I've discovered that if I reboot the server I can ping the Router for about 5 - 7 minutes before the error occurs.

Even though the pings to the router report general failure and the router no longer forwards packets via dnat to the server, the server can still see the internet through the router and packet flows through are running well. Just the error as indicated. If I restart the server again then it can see the router just fine.

I've turned off all IPV6 I can find. Firewall is off on the server.
IP on server is static and I've even changed network cards. The services that this affects is VPN backwards and forwards.
Please if any one can think of something I haven't tried yet I will be very grateful.

Routing Table:

[image: Routing Table]

Traceroute:

[image: Traceroute]

IPConfig

```
Windows IP Configuration  
  
   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : MW-DBPOTCH  
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :  
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid  
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : Yes  
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No  
  
PPP adapter RAS (Dial In) Interface:  
  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :  
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : RAS (Dial In) Interface  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.100(Preferred)  
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255  
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :  
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled  
  
Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:  
  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :  
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 78-98-E8-C1-7D-21  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.90(Preferred)  
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0  
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.55  
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8  
                                       8.8.4.4  
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled  
  
Unknown adapter Local Area Connection 3:  
  
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :  
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Windows Adapter V9 #3  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-71-78-73-AD  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  
  
Unknown adapter Local Area Connection 2:  
  
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :  
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Windows Adapter V9 #2  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-11-66-B0-E5  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  
  
Unknown adapter Local Area Connection:  
  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :  
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Windows Adapter V9  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-7A-46-EC-20  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.0.1(Preferred)  
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252  
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Monday, October 17, 2022 8:47:12 PM  
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, October 17, 2023 8:47:11 PM  
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :  
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.0.2  
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled  
  
Ethernet adapter LAN2PRINTER:  
  
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :  
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : HPE Ethernet 1Gb 2-port 361i Adapter #2  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 28-92-4A-2D-EE-B5  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  
  
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:  
  
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :  
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : HPE Ethernet 1Gb 2-port 361i Adapter  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 28-92-4A-2D-EE-B4  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  
  
Tunnel adapter isatap.{7A46EC20-3C45-44A4-9DAD-AD3BE5E5581D}:  
  
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :  
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  
  
Tunnel adapter isatap.{43FF4FF7-B6D9-44A8-9D98-E9ADBF498EB8}:  
  
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :  
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  
  
Tunnel adapter isatap.{6E06F030-7526-11D2-BAF4-00600815A4BD}:  
  
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :  
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: What is 192.168.0.100? Do you have 2 separate addresses on the interface? Provide `IPCONFIG /ALL` (as code-formatted text, not as a picture).

Answer (score 1):

I obviously needed sleep, and came back with an open mind.

The firewall was off, which is one of the first things I checked.

Then I checked the AV software, while it didn't have a firewall configured, it did still have the ability to block network traffic, and it determined that router should be blocked due to RDP attacks.

Thank you for everyone who put time in to try and assist me. I really appreciate it.